# Production ready Socket server in Java

Tags: java, sockets

There are many tutorials where explains about socket server/client sides, but all them are very trivial. Is there any tutorial for production ready code? I'm new in sockets. There is a client, that sends strings to server. I must create the server side. in server side I read string from client and after some manipulation saves them in db. I must response to client only IF I get string like "Error" for example. and if there are no any daya from client in 30 secs, I must close client connection, but server side must works. **this is my test Client side:**

```
public class ClientSideSocket2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverName = "localhost";
        int port = 5555;
        String line = "";
        Socket client = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
            client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

            PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                messages.add("Message " + i+1);
            }
            messages.add("abc");

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                toServer.println(messages.get(i));
                if ((line = fromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Responce from server: " + line);
                }
            }

            toServer.close();
            fromServer.close();


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and my server side:**

```
public class TRSServerInterface implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    boolean runner = true;
    String message = "";

    public TRSServerInterface() {}

    @Override
    public void run() { // default run method of Thread class and Runnable interface

        try {
            int serverPort = 5555;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                //get the input and output streams

                PrintWriter toClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                do {
                    message = fromClient.readLine();
                    System.out.println("From client > " + message);
                    if (message.equals("abc")) {
                        toClient.println("Message from server");
                    }
                    else {
                        toClient.println("");
                    }
                } while (!message.equals(""));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
//          try {
//              objectOut.close();
//              objectIn.close();
//              socket.close();
//          } catch (IOException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
        }
    }
}
```

is my solution corrent and how I can close connection with client if there are no any data in 30 secs.

Comment: If you're asking for tutorials, then your question is off-topic. If you're asking for a code reveiw, then it should be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are several production ready frameworks that should be used instead of rolling your own. Socket timeouts can be used to control how long different operations are allowed to take before an exception is thrown.

Comment: yes, there is netty.io for example, but they all work in async mode. My server should't work in async mode.

Comment: No they don't "all work in async mode". While Netty has mostly async functionality, it's only one of the numerous frameworks.

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise in Googling for you.

Comment: @Kayaman wow giving homework on StackOverflows. The audacity!